# Use Find/Replace to clear vbNullString

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that is generated as a report in our Enterprise system and downloaded into an Excel spreadsheet. Blank cells in the resulting spreadsheet are not really blank, even though no data is present - and the blank cells do Not contain a 'space' character.

For example, the following cell formula in A2 returns TRUE (if A1 is a blank cell):

```
=IF(A1="","TRUE","FALSE")
```

However,

```
=ISBLANK(A1)
```

returns FALSE.

You can replicate this problem by typing an apostrophe (') in a cell and copying the cell. Then, use Paste Special...Values to paste to another cell and the apostrophe is not visible in the pasted cell, nor in the Formula Bar. There appears to be a clear cell, but it will evaluate to FALSE using ISBLANK.
This causes sorting to result in the fake blank cells at the top of an ascending sort, when they need to be at the bottom of the sort.

I can use a vba loop to fix the fake blanks, to loop through every column and evaluate

```
IF Cell.VALUE = "" Then
   Cell.Clear
```

but because the spreadsheet has tens of thousands of rows of data and as many as 50 columns, this adds substantial overhead to the program and I would prefer to use FIND and Replace.

Here is the code that does not currently work:

```
Range("ZZ1").Copy
Range("Table1[#All]").Select
With Selection
   .Replace What:="", Replacement:=.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues, xlNone, False, False), _ 
   LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
   ReplaceFormat:=False
End With
```

The following things do not work to clear the fake blank cells either:

```
Replacement:= vbnullstring
Replacement:= ""
Replacement:= Cells.Clear
Replacement:= Cells.ClearContents
Replacement:= Cells.Value = ""
```

I have tried 20 other things that do not work either.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: This is nice and quick. It does remove all formulae and formatting though.

Comment: If formating is important I guess you can split into two ranges of rows, do the first one, copy and paste format, do the second, copy and paste format. To keep formulas would require to loop all cells, but I assume an exported file won't contain formulas.

Answer (score 1):

A variant array provides an efficient way of handling the false empties:

```
Sub CullEm()
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim X

X = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
  For lngCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
   If Len(X(lngRow, lngCol)) = 0 Then X(lngRow, lngCol) = vbNullString
  Next
Next
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2 = X

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are searching for a hidden `.PrefixCharacter` which are not covered by the standard replacement function. For more information on this you might want to visit MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194949.aspx

In order to find and replace these you'll have to use the `.Find` function because it can look at the formulas (rather than only at a cell's value). Here is a short sample code to illustrate that:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpTest()

Dim cell As Range
Dim rngTest As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String

Set rngTest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:G7")
Set cell = rngTest.Find("", LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart)
If Not cell Is Nothing Then
    strFirstAddress = cell.Address
    Do
        cell.Value = vbNullString
        Set cell = rngTest.FindNext(cell)
    Loop While strFirstAddress <> cell.Address And Not cell Is Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out anything that you could put in `Replacement` to get that to work. I'm afraid you're stuck looping. You can reduce the overhead by using `.Find` instead of looping through every cell.

```
Sub ClearBlanks()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstAdd As String
    Dim rFoundAll As Range

    Set rng = Sheet1.UsedRange

    Set rFound = rng.Find(vbNullString, , xlValues, xlWhole)

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirstAdd = rFound.Address
        Do
            If rFoundAll Is Nothing Then
                Set rFoundAll = rFound
            Else
                Set rFoundAll = Application.Union(rFound, rFoundAll)
            End If
            Set rFound = rng.FindNext(rFound)
        Loop Until rFound.Address = sFirstAdd
    End If

    If Not rFoundAll Is Nothing Then
        rFoundAll.ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the table filter to select the (seemingly) blank cells in each column and clear the contents.  This should be quicker than finding each blank cell.

```
Sub clearBlankTableEntries()
    Dim tbl As ListObject, c As Byte

    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("testTable")
    For c = 1 To tbl.Range.Columns.Count
        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=c, Criteria1:="="
        Range(tbl.Name & "[Column" & c & "]").ClearContents
        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=c
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I did not indicate in my question that some of the columns in the table do not contain any fake blank cells. This code works nicely for the columns with blanks. But if a column has every cell populated with data (no blanks in it), the entire column is cleared of its existing data.

Comment: That's not good! You can check for this situation and only clear the contents when the filtered table is displaying more than just the header row:    `If (tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1) Then Range(tbl.Name & "[Column" & c & "]").ClearContents`