# Ctrl + Down in blank column hits ghost cell and stops?

Tags: excel, csv, ctrl

I have a file that is csv and converted to excel.  it is a data extract from a CRM application and it outputs ~ 90K lines.

When I use the <kbd>Ctrl + Down</kbd> to navigate to the last used range of the data, I hit a "ghost row".  My active cell stops on a cell with no input in it. it is just blank...  Anyone know what could cause the phantom input that is haulting the <kbd>Ctrl + Down</kbd> action?

It is ruining my ability to write a macro to handle the data because the row changes each time the data is exported.

Comment: If you [clear all](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/clear-cells-of-contents-or-formats-9ff6b8ff-1afd-495f-8ad8-8c1f6f82a9d6) on this "ghost row" does it still occur?

Comment: There are data in any line after the "ghost" cell or the last data cell occurs before it?

Comment: Check this post for an answer. The problem has a similar ghost blank.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881003/use-find-replace-to-clear-vbnullstring

Comment: @Dyno, when I clear contents in the cell it still catches on the blank cell.

Comment: @Magnetron, there is nothing in the cells beneath the "ghost" cell.  Everything in the column is showing blank (no spaces determinable in the formula bar)

Comment: @the dude, thanks for sharing the thread, I will read more in depth and see if a solution presents itself! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a new line character (/n) present, in the end of the last row, in the original csv.
This could be creating the ghost row.

Try removing this and check.